# Перемещение всей сцены

Tags: unity3d

В юнити на сцене происходит загрузка другой сцены в режиме LoadSceneMode.Additive, можно ли как-то эту сцену подвинуть целиком из скрипта, например как родительский объект?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Гуглеж показывает что `LoadScene` возвращает `SceneManagement.Scene` у которого есть метод `GetRootGameObjects`. Загрузите сцену и подвиньте все её рутовые объекты. Выглядеть будет так будто вы подвинули сцену как единое целое.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Метод LoadScene ничего не возращает :/

Comment: `public static SceneManagement.Scene LoadScene (string sceneName, SceneManagement.LoadSceneParameters parameters);` - возвращает.

Comment: В общем сделал не так, как предлагал Станислав, но все равно сработало: просто создал метод, в котором в цикле каждый объект из массива GetRootGameObjects передвигается и подписал его потом в событие OnSceneLoaded. Оказалось проще, чем я думал.